# inner DIV not accessible using document.getElementById

Tags: html, accessibility

see below html

```
<Div id="one">
 <Div id="two">

 </Div>
</Div>
```

when i am accessing div "two" with "`document.getElementById("two")`...am getting null.

Comment: Try <div> instead of <Div>?  Shouldn't make a difference, but lowercase is correct although browsers often accept mixed case tags.

Comment: Could you post you entire code here? Maybe you're trying to use JavaScript before DOM is ready?

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me.

```
<body onload="javascript:test();">
<Div id="one">
 <Div id="two">

 </Div>
</Div>


function test()
{
alert(document.getElementById("two"));
}
```

and I receive a messagebox which displays

> [object]